# Why does the Moore-Penrose inverse appear to give an exact solution for overdetermined linear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have an overdetermined system of linear equations, $Ax=b$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m > n$. In general, there is no exact solution, and we know that if $A$ has independent columns, then the best-fit or least-squares solution is given by the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$ multiplied with $b$:

$x_{LS} = A^{+}b = [A^TA]^{-1}A^Tb$.

This can be obtained by writing out the least-squares optimisation problem and then solving it by setting the gradient of the objective with respect to $x$ to $0$. However, consider the following simpler derivation:

$Ax=b$

$[A^TA]^{-1}A^TAx=[A^TA]^{-1}A^Tb$ (left-multiplying both sides by the Moore-Penrose inverse)

$[A^TA]^{-1}[A^TA]x=[A^TA]^{-1}A^Tb$

$x=[A^TA]^{-1}A^Tb$

So this appears to suggest that the least-squares solution is an exact solution. There must be something wrong with this derivation, but I can't place my finger on it. What is wrong with it? And how come it ends up giving the least-squares solution, even though I wasn't solving for that?

Comment: The derivation is correct: you get that *if* $Ax = b$ then it must be the case that $x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$. If $Ax = b$ has no solutions then this is vacuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix $A$ has full column rank (that is, its columns are linearly independent), then a system $Ax=b$ has at most one solution.

In your derivation, you are *assuming* that a solution exists and, of course, if a solution exists, it is also the least squares solution.

So what you proved is *if $x$ is a solution of $Ax=b$, where $A$ has full column rank, then $x=A^+b$*.

Comment: how can it be, for example a linear $$A:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3,$$ surjective?

Comment: @janmarqz I can't understand, sorry. Read again: *if $x$ is a solution*. If the system has no solution, then $A^+b$ is obviously not a solution.

Comment: the problem is in your 1st phrase because even in the case of full rank, if $b$ is outside the ${\rm Im}A$ then $Ax=b$ hasn't at least one solution.

Comment: @janmarqz The system has *at most one solution*. This means it can have none, or, if it has, then the solution is unique.

Comment: you are invincible, kudos!

Comment: Thanks! I also realised this after thinking about it a bit more. Actually what I implicitly had in mind is that I should just be able to plug this solution for $x$ back into the original equation and get equality, and hence this derivation itself establishes the existence of a solution (as long as the obtained value for $x$ is well-defined). But while that would be true for a scalar equation, it's not true here because matrix multiplication isn't commutative in general. That's what I had neglected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the abuse of writing $Ax=b$, it is necessary that $b$ is in the image of $A$ considered as a linear map from $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ to write like that.

One should write $Ax\approx b$ instead, so $x\approx [A^{\top}A]^{-1}A^{\top}b$ is the approximation of least squares method.

Comment: further, it can happen to have problems if $A^{\top}A$ is not invertible.

Comment: The matrix $A$ has linearly independent columns if and only if $A^TA$ is invertible, because $A^TA$ has the same rank as $A$ and is square.

Comment: no problem with that